# Is it possible to import a database table to Drools Guvnor as a decision table?

Tags: database, drools, guvnor

We will be having data fed in this database table regularly, and I was wondering if it was possible to import this data on a timely basis into Drools Guvnor?

Comment: Can you be any more specific? Do you want to control the whole logic through a database or only the 'properties' of the decision table? It is possible to make direct connection to DB from Drools, or you could simply insert your facts to working memory based on the data in DB

Comment: There's nothing out of the box. Also it would not make sense to do this, as the only reason to have a decision table in Guvnor is to enable editing of it in Guvnor. And every time the database table was updated, you would be replacing all of those edits.

Comment: Hi I just want to store the "properties" of the decision table. I understand the drawbacks of this but the client doesn't want to use Guvnor's interface for editing the rules.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to maintain rules in a database table, then you should be looking at rule templates:

http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.0.1.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#d0e4969

Rule templates provide a relatively simple mechanism for merging DRL with data.

FWIW - The documentation for this in the manual is poor, so here is a hint on the kind of thing you need to do:

To generate rules from a combination of database data and a template, you will need to import `org.drools.template.jdbc.ResultSetGenerator`. This class can be used to generate DRL code from a database query result set and a template.

```
// Get results from your DB query...
resultSet = preparedStmt.executeQuery();
// Generate the DRL...
resultSetGenerator = new ResultSetGenerator();
String drl = resultSetGenerator.compile(resultSet, 
         new FileInputStream("path/to/template.drt"));
```

Then you create a package through the API and add that generated DRL to it.

Comment: Yes we have tried to use rule templates and upload them manually in Drools. Is there a way to automatically feed the data in these spreadsheets in Guvnor? I would prefer feeding directly from the DB which the client would just update through an interface but I'm all open for any options.

Comment: The point is that they should *not* be in Guvnor. Guvnor is not the runtime environment. It is a place for editing rules. Therefore if you intend to maintain rules in a database table, then those rules should not be in Guvnor.

Comment: I understand your point. The only thing is that there is an immense amount of combinations for the available data which would prove difficult to manage in Guvnor's interface. I obviously am not an expert on this which is probably why I'm having a hard time understanding what can and what cannot go into Guvnor.

Comment: The "rule templates" that you can create in Guvnor are completely different things from the 'Expert' rule templates. Or at least, how you use them is completely different. I have added some example code above demonstrating how to generate DRL from a database result set and an 'Expert' template.